# how to export results to CSV in a loop

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, export-to-csv, sql-scripts

I have a SQL query

```
       select time,t_count,sum(t_count) over (order by time) as
       cumulative_t_count ,cumulative_t_count/sum(t_count) as percentage_cumulative count,state,hour from (select distinct
       time,count(distinct num_id) as t_count,state,hour from (select * from
       public.table1 where day=1 and time>0 order by time)as A group by
       time,hour,state order by hour,state )B where state=1 and hour=1;
```

which gives me a results in the below format:

```
time  t_count  cumulative_t_count  state  hour
_____ _____  _________________     ____  ____
1      10          10               1    1
2      20          30               1    1
3      30          60               1    1
4      60          120              1    1
```

Likewise I have 80 state and hour from 0-23.I want to export all the results to CSV files  by changing the state from 1-80 and for the hours 1,7,14,19.So now I am manually changing the state and hour in the above code and exporting the results as CSV.But it seems I have to change state 1 to 80 and hours 1,7,14,19 for each state.

```
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..80 LOOP


  FOR i IN 1,7,14,19 LOOP
      /copy ( select time,t_count,sum(t_count) over (order by time) as
       cumulative_t_count ,cumulative_t_count/sum(t_count) as     percentage_cumulative count,state,hour from (select distinct
       time,count(distinct num_id) as t_count,state,hour from (select * from
       public.table1 where day=1 and time>0 order by time)as A group by
       time,hour,state order by hour,state )B where state=i and hour=j)

     To '/tmp/state_i_hour_j.csv' With CSV
 END LOOP

END LOOP
```

But this did not work.I also want to export each result set in CSV format.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `\copy` is a `psql` only command, **not** a SQL statement - that's the reason you will not find it in the [list of SQL commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html) - you can't use that inside a PL/pgSQL function

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but copy command won't work because I am not a superuser.So how can I export files in a loop as CSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to do this the once, you can use the following to create the sql statements you need. You can then copy the output records and execute them.

```
WITH states AS
(SELECT generate_series(1,80) as i),
hours AS
(SELECT j FROM (values (1),(14),(17),(19) ) s(j))
SELECT 'copy ( select time,t_count,sum(t_count) over (order by time) as
       cumulative_t_count ,cumulative_t_count/sum(t_count) as     percentage_cumulative count,state,hour from (select distinct
       time,count(distinct num_id) as t_count,state,hour from (select * from
       public.table1 where day=1 and time>0 order by time)as A group by
       time,hour,state order by hour,state )B where state=' ||i || ' and hour=' ||j || ')

     To ''/tmp/state_' ||i || '_hour_' ||j || '.csv'' With CSV;' from states,hours
```

Comment: This SQL query gives the below `copy ( select time,t_count,sum(t_count) over (order by time)` in the table 320 rows but no CSV  are generated in the destination

Comment: All the query does is create the query statements you need. You then need to execute them, e.g. by copying and pasting them in PGadmin.